# Is it possible to move Azure Web Application to different location?

Tags: azure

I have an Azure Web Application currently deployed at South UK. I would like to move it to West Europe (the latency to my location is about the same, but West Europe is by far cheaper than South UK).

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Create new Web App and deploy to it? Or you want to keep the azurewebsites.net URL?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for transferring a Web App between regions. You will have to recreate it in another region. If you want to use the same Web App name, you will first have to delete your existing Web App.